# How do I use parameter expansion in find?

Tags: linux

I can use the `for` command to change .dat files to .txt files like this

```
for f in *.dat
do
  mv $f ${f/.dat/.txt}
done
```

where `${f/.dat/.txt}` modifies the `.dat` in each filename to `.txt`.  But how can I do this with `find`?  An attempt to use `{}` as a variable fails.

```
find . -type f -exec echo ${} \;
-bash: ${}: bad substitution
```

I can get further by assigning `{}` to a parameter like this

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat'  -exec echo `f={}; echo $f` \;
```

but an attempt at substitution fails

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat'  -exec echo `f={}; echo $(echo ${f/.dat/.txt})` \;
```

prints

```
./file1.dat
./file2.dat
```

not

```
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
```

Does anyone know how to make `find` behave the way I want it?

Comment: "An attempt to use {} as a variable fails" because it's not a variable, it's a placeholder: `find . -type f -exec echo {} \;`

Comment: @miken32 Sure but I can assign `{}` to a variable and use the variable.  However parameter expansion doesn't work on the variable and that is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216780/why-does-bash-parameter-expansion-not-work-inside-systemd-service-files) from @celada about `systemd` points to the solution.  The `-exec` in `find` does not invoke a shell, so although some parameter manipulation is supported, parameter expansion like `$f{/.dat/.txt}` isn't.

So the trick is to exec a shell and then escape the dollar signs like this

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat'  -exec sh -c "f={}; mv \$f \${f/dat/txt}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to modify filename and generate cmds that you pass to bash, i.e.

```
cat fixer.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
{
        outFile=$0
        sub(/\.txt/, ".dat", outFile) ; print "mv "$0 " " outFile
}

chmod 755 fixer.awk

find . -type f -name '*.dat' | /path/to/fixer.awk
```

**output**

```
mv 34274841/file1.txt 34274841/file1.dat
mv 34274841/file2.txt 34274841/file2.dat
```

When you're happy with that output, and certain there are no unforeseen consequences ;-) , then execute

```
 find . -type f -name '*.dat' | /path/to/fixer.awk | bash
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks @shelter.  This is a sensible approach.  However I was looking for a one-liner without requiring the use of custom helper scripts.  I like the pipe to `bash` - I haven't encountered that before.

Answer (score 0):

You could just skip the `exec` parameter and echo the output to sed instead:

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat' | sed 's/.dat/.txt/'
```